# how to restart the windows service automatically with 5 seconds, if it is stopped manually?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, service, windows-services

I have a windows service that should run on the client's system 24*7 (local server system). If the client tries to stop the service manually, how do I invoke the service within 5-10 seconds? I have already placed the startup type as automatic. But, this feature works only when the system is restarted.

Need to restart the service automatically with 5-10 seconds if it is manually stopped.

Comment: Don't give the user permissions that allow them to control system services if they're not meant to. On the other hand, if it's *their* machine, under their control, you're not in the correct position to dictate what code runs on their machine.

Comment: Hi @Damien_The_Unbeliever,

The user will have admin rights, as well as this process, should happen. Is there any other way to handle it?

Comment: Then you have to accept that they'll always be able to defeat any technical measures you try to put in place to try to keep the service running and you need to use *non-technical* measures to keep the service running. I.e. it's a disciplinary issue, not a technical one.

Comment: The system administrators have the rights to shut down whatever they want. So by asking this question you want a solution to fool them around, don't you? Then that's not an appropriate question to be discussed. Others might be led to help you create a malware.

Answer (score 1):

- Option A:

  Write another service that will watch periodically for that service and start it, if it has stopped.
- Option B:

  Write a script/application that will watch for that service and start it, if it has stopped and run that script/application periodically from the Task Scheduler

Comment: Other than these methods, do we have any other possibilities with inbuilt default programs/applications?

Comment: well, if I know any other I would have added them to my answer - or do you think I will have some premium information I will only offer if someone will ask for? ;o)

Comment: Thanks, @Sir Rufo. We'll try based on the above method with a few workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a Windows Task Scheduler to check for the status of the service and restart it if it is stopped. Here are the steps:

1. Open Task Scheduler by pressing the Windows key + R, typing "taskschd.msc" and press Enter.
2. Click on "Create Task" in the right-hand pane.
3. Name the task something like "Service Restart".
4. Under the "General" tab, make sure "Run whether the user is logged on or not" is selected.
5. Under the "Triggers" tab, click "New" and set up a trigger to start the task "On an event" with the following settings:

- Log: System
- Source: Service Control Manager
- Event ID: 7036
- Delay: 5 seconds (or whatever delay you prefer)

6. Under the "Actions" tab, click "New" and set up an action to run the following command:

- Program/script: "cmd.exe"
- Add arguments: "/c net start <service_name>"
  imp: Replace <service_name> with the service name you want to restart.

7. Under the "Conditions" tab, uncheck all boxes.

Under the "Settings" tab, select "Allow task to be run on demand" and "Run task as soon as possible after a scheduled start is missed".

Click "OK" to save the task.

Now, when the service is stopped manually, it will trigger an event in the Windows Event Viewer, which will in turn trigger the task you just created. The task will then wait for the specified delay and attempt to start the service.

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the [windows task scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler). You could write an windows log entry when the service will be stopped with `EventLog.WriteEntry`. This log entry can be used as a trigger in the scheduler and start the service with the `NET START` command again.

Comment: Please do not post link only answers. Add the relevant information from that link to your question to keep the information even if the link will go down in the future